# Visual Studio 2005 : debugging windows services not possible

Tags: debugging, windows-services, visual-studio-2005

Since a coupple of days, I cannot attach my Visual studio 2005's debbuger to my Windows Services. In the windows these services are grayed.

Anyone has an idea?